# Destroy process-less console windows left by Visual Studio debug sessions

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

A known bug with a Windows XP security update KB978037 can occur with Visual Studio 2005 (and 2008) where sometimes if you restart a debugging session on a console app then the console window doesn't get closed even though the owner process no longer exists. The problem is discussed further here:

[Visual studio debug console sometimes stays open and is impossible to close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402875/visual-studio-debug-console-sometimes-stays-open-and-is-impossible-to-close)

These zombie windows then can not be closed via the Taskbar or via the TaskManager, and typically require a power off/on to get rid of them. Over the period of even a single day you can accumulate quite a few of them, which clog up your TaskBar and are generally annoying.

I thought I would knock up a simple C++ Win32 utility to attempt to call DestroyWindow() on these windows by passing the windows handle as a cmd-line argument and converting it to a HWND.

I'm converting the handle from a string by parsing it as a DWORD then casting the DWORD to a HWND. This appears to be working as if I call GetWindowInfo() on the handle it succeeds. However calling DestroyWindow() on the handle fails with error 5 (access denied), presumably because the caller process (i.e. my app) doesn't own the window in question.

Any ideas as to how I might get rid of the zombie windows, either via the above approach or any other alternative short of rebooting? I'm in a corporate environment so installing/uninstalling updates/service-packs etc isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not what you want to hear but the only way to get rid of these windows *is* by rebooting the computer

Apparently the windows team is trying to fix it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/debugger/archive/2010/03/11/help-my-console-windows-won-t-go-away.aspx

but not much seems to be happening

Comment: Is it just these particular windows that are impossible to clear up, or does that apply to any windows that lack an associated process?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's hot fix for Windows XP and Windows 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982551)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still a problem with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7!

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995493/visual-studio-cannot-build-a-simple-project-more-than-once)