# Visual Studio - Cannot build a simple project more than once

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I try to build a project twice in successon, i get the following error

```
Error 2 Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Release\iFileUploader.exe" 
to "bin\Release\iFileUploader.exe". The process cannot access the 
file 'bin\Release\iFileUploader.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

If I close Visual Studio and reopen it, I can compile it again but only once.

I have my projects hosted on a Windows network share.  The server runs Windows 2008 R2 and Im on a Windows 7 machine and Ive tried setting everyone full control on the share and the folder permission, to no avail.

Ive even run the Unlocker program and checked the Windows Share & Storage Manager to see if anything is using it and nothing is!  I cant delete the file when this happens either until I close VS.

Is there a setting I am missing in Visual Studio?!

---

**UPDATE**

Have removed all antivirus/antispam, disabled firewall.. so zero security.

Have disabled "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"

Visual Studio is some how the colprupt with not releasing the handle

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Another thread that has exactly the same problem but from years ago !!

[Destroy process-less console windows left by Visual Studio debug sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817525/destroy-process-less-console-windows-left-by-visual-studio-debug-sessions)

---

**UPDATE**

I copied the files locally, and that didnt work.  So I created a new project and then copied all the code in to the new project and now its working (with the files stored locally)

Comment: Is it a service? Is it running when you compile the project? Maybe your postbuild scripts makes it run.

Comment: I have the same issue on my work computer. I suspect that the ForeFront anti-virus is part of the problem. Do you use an anti-virus program? Can you turn it off and see if the problems disappears?

Comment: Please see updated comments in question

Answer (score 1):

check your antivirus program is using it or not.

Alternatively use Process Explorer and find for the string - "iFileUploader.exe" and see who's using it. You can easily get the handle and close it.

Comment: Not antivirus as removed and rebooted and still same problem.

Comment: What happens when you try to kill the handles? are you able to? This could have been Visual Studio Bug

Comment: The hanldes are associated to the same PID as Visual Studio. So killing them, kills Visual Studio

Comment: I don't think reopening will reestablish the link to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- Check if you don't have a process `iFileUploader.exe` already running in the Windows Task Manager.
- Check that nobody is not running a project that could use `iFileUploader.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that where you have created an instance of the StreamReader or    StreamWriter that you have closed the stream.

For example I would create at the application level a StreamReader / StreamWriter instance and set it to null

```
Class SomeClass
{
  public StreamWriter streamwrtFileToCreate = null;
  public FileStream fstreamFileStream = null
  public SomeMethod(string FileName, string FilePath)
  {   
    FileStream fstreamFileStream = new FileStream(@FileName + @FilePath, FileMode.Create);
    streamwrtFileToCreate = new StreamWriter(fstreamUpdateRpt);
    streamwrtUpdateRpt.AutoFlush = true;
  }
}
```

Also it would help if you post the exact example of code that you are using when you create the FileStream Instance

Comment: but im not actually running the program

Comment: Where I have got streams, i use `using () {}`

Answer (score 0):

Christian even if you are have your Stream in a using(){} do not declare a new variable of StreamReader for example do not do this

```
using(StreamReader streamReade = new StreamReader)
{
  ..... // if you do you will run into that stream being locked
}
//Declare the StreamReader variable out side of the using and then within the using do something like this.

StreamReader streamReader = null
using(streamReader = new StreamReader()
{

}
```

Comment: good to know cheers, but wasn't a streamreader issue, just some Visual Studio bug. Once I copied the code to a new project, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VS 2012 windows 7.
Root cause is Avast Antivirus.

> Fix is disable Avast whenever needed to work on C++ console
> applications

(or)

> ->Go to Avast Settings
>
> ->Active Protection
>
> ->File System Shield (Customize)
>
> ->uncheck Scan programs when executing